# Is there a way to to convert a Hashmap to XML format and vice versa without using any additional libraries and using Java JDK 11

Tags: java, java-11

Is there a way to to convert a Hashmap to XML format and vice versa without using any additional libraries and using Java JDK 11

I have tried to google and find any other methods but have been unsuccessful and suggestions?

Comment: You could use `XMLEncoder`.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. The following code can be used to convert a Hashmap to XML format:

```java
HashMap h = new HashMap();
String outputFileName = "output.xml";

OutputStream outstream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("output.txt");

try {
    // Map mapping values to strings in an OutputStreamWriter object - this is where the xml conversion takes place
    OutputStreamWriter writer=new OutputStreamWriter(outstream);
    writer.writeUTF(h.toString()); 
} finally { 
    if (writer != null) writer.
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, which suggests you copied it from somewhere else. Please post complete code, and if this was copied from something you do not have the copyright to, consider deleting your answer, or at minimum post attribution. Also, the code as shown cannot possible work as 1) `getResourceAsStream(..)` returns an `InputStream`, not an `OutputStream` and 2) `OutputStreamWriter` does not have a `writeUTF` method and 3) even if it had, `h.toString()` would not generate an XML presentation of the hashmap.